# It is about using grids and colors in Folium

Tags: folium

could someone kindly provide recommendations for using Python coding with Folium to incorporate both colors and grids within a polygon?

I anticipate being able to visualize my polygons representing two distinct sets of information: one based on colors and the other on a grid pattern.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please take a look at the [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page. You can improve your question by including what you’ve already tried.